# Starting a simple HTTP-server using "npm" without installing npm

Tags: node.js, linux, web-services, npm, npm-install

Which command do I need to use to start a simple HTTP server using "npm", the specified port to be used is port 8080. Also, I don't have to download the npm package. The only hint I got is that I can download the basic web server packet, also from there I can specify the port 8080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the http server has been configured with the x-server name at port xxxx, you can start it with the command:

```
x-server -p xxxx
```

for example if my server's name is simple-http-server at port 8080:

```
simple-http-server -p 8080
```

would start it.

for the next exercice:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Once npm is installed, the command is simply: `http-server -p 8080` (without writing '`npm`' at the beginning of the line).

Comment: This works only when the npm package `http-server` was installed globally with `-g` option. Otherwise you have to run it with `npx` in front to grab it from the current-dir.